# Is C++11 mutex only uses static initialization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Does C++11 standard guarantees mutex doesn't use dynamic initialization?  For example, if we declare a global variable of mutex type, and then use it in the constructor of another global variable in another TU, will the order of construction be a concern here?

Comment: What do you mean "zero initialized"? The standard guarantees that the mutex is constructed unlocked, that's it.

Comment: @Cicada, I have a question because Google's spinlock is able to do LINKER_INITIALIZED: http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/base/spinlock.h so that it is initialized even before any constructor is run, therefore can be used by the constructors of global variables without concerning the order of constructors.

Comment: Do you mean static initialization?

Comment: @T.C.: Except for the one given in 30.4.1.2.1 [thread.mutex.class]. ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant Ah, I was reading the `Mutex` requirements in [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex] :P

Comment: @HowardHinnant, the std::mutex's constructor is constexpr as you pointed out, so does it support my use case?

Comment: @icando: I am not positive. The intent of the committee is yes, a `std::mutex` with static storage duration is constructed with static initialization. However I suspect that the current state is that an implementation is allowed to use dynamic initialization. clang/libc++ on OS X uses static initialization. An interesting survey would answer that question for other toolsets and platforms.  It might be that all implementations provide static initialization even though not required to do so.

Comment: P.S. For a given toolset/platform the question can be answered by creating a test program and inspecting the resultant assembly language.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, testing on specific platform is useful, but the main purpose of my question here is to make sure my use case is blessed by the standard, so I don't have to worry it will break in the future even if it works currently.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of imprecise language is confusing matters here.  The term "zero initialized" has a *specific* meaning in the Standard that does not apply to `mutex`, nor does it apply to your stated use case.

So let's level-set here with an understanding of what you're really asking, by looking at your example:

> if we declare a global variable of mutex type, and then use it in the
>   constructor of another global variable in another CU, will the order
>   of construction be a concern here?

We're still a little vague here, and the rules governing initialization of non-member variables are subtle, so I'm going to sum up with what I believe is in general sound advice.

**In general, do not rely on the order of initialization of non-member variables.**

This is a great reason to not use global variables at all, whenever you can avoid it.

Comment: thanks, so what's the standard term I should use if I want to say some class is already in a valid state after zero-initialization or constant-initialization, so that it can be used by the constructor of another global variable?

Comment: @icando: Just ask whether static initialization suffices for that class. Anyway, you might want to read *[basic.start.init]* and *[dcl.init]*.

Comment: @Deduplicator, the standard is too formal.  After reading a little bit the chapters you pointed out, I got a sense since std::mutex has a constexpr default constructor, so my use case here is blessed by the standard?  Am I reading it correctly?

Comment: @icando Yes, a `std::mutex` is completely initialized during static initialization, because the ctor is `constexpr`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, do you mind writing an answer so I can accept?  This one is completely off-topic and incorrect IMHO, as it talks about general case and says "no" to my use case but I was asking std::mutex specifically and it is in fact "yes" according to your comment and C++11 standard.

Answer (score -3):

Surely yes. It is a concern in any case if you are talking about interaction between globals in the startup phase of the program (ie: before the `main`() invocation).

Also if it could be zero initialized (indipendently of what that exactly means), that initialization would occour during the constructor of the mutex itself, so the order of construction would be a concern.

Comment: zero-initialization is a precisely defined term of the standard, not some vague thing.

Comment: By saying zero initialized, I mean it is initialized at program loading time.  Just like defining a global variable `int a = 0;` will make `a` initialized before any constructors run.  I have this question because Google's SpinLock implementation has this feature: http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/base/spinlock.h

Comment: @Deduplicator, sorry but I know that an integer or a pointer should be zero initialized, but what that does mean for a mutex object?

Comment: See [basic.start.init] and [dcl.init].